# Calculation of a line-integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, line-integrals

How do I calculate $\int_L (y+x)dl,$
where
$$
L: \begin{cases}x = 1+t+\frac{2}{3}t^\frac{3}{2}\\y= t-\frac{2}{3}t^\frac{3}{2}-1\\
0 ≤ t ≤ 3
\end{cases}$$

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Isn't $x+y$ just equal to $2t$, in this case?

Comment: Don't look for a theorem! Look for a definition.

Comment: Isn't $\mathrm{d}\ell = \sqrt{(\mathrm{d}x)^2+(\mathrm{d}y)^2}$?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin how did you get that?

Comment: @MattiP. yes, but can we directly integrate 2t? i think I must first determine dℓ?

Comment: Your original integral has "dl".  It is impossible to integrate x+ y with respect to l without knowing how x and y are related to l and that means knowing how t is related to l.

Comment: If as Alexey Burdin suggested, "l" is "arclength" so that $dl=\sqr{dx^2+dy^2}$ then, since $x= 1+ t+ (2/3)t^{3/2}$ and $y= t-(2/3)t^{3/2}$, $dx= (1+ t^{1/2}) dt$, $dy= (1- t^{1/2})dt$ so $dl= \sqrt{(1+ 2t^{1/2}+ t)+ (1- 2t^{1/2}+ t}dt= \sqrt{2+ 2t}dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the value $dl$ is nothing but $\sqrt{(dx(t))^2+(dy(t))^2}dt$. Comes intuitively from the Pythagorean theorem as we are approximating the curve $L$ with infinitely small tangent vectors(and they have infinitely small components $dx$ and $dy$), just as we would split the $x$-axis into very small pieces with a normal Riemann integral. In fact a normal integral is nothing but a line-integral along the path $y=0$. And for $x$ and $y$ we just plug in their parametrizations and integrate along the curve. So calculating:
$$\int_{L}(y+x)dl$$
$$=\int_{0}^{3}(t-\frac{2}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}}-1+1+t+\frac{2}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}})\sqrt{(\frac{d}{dt}(1+t+\frac{2}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}}))^2+(\frac{d}{dt}(t-\frac{2}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}}-1))^2}dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{3}2t\sqrt{2t+2}dt$$
Substituting $u=2t+2$ gives the following:
$$\int_{0}^{3}2t\sqrt{2t+2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{2}^{8}(u-2)\sqrt{u}du=\frac{1}{2}\int_{2}^{8}u^{\frac{3}{2}}du-\int_{2}^{8}\sqrt{u}du$$
These should be easy enough integrals to do. Final answer is:
$$\int_{L}(y+x)=\frac{232\sqrt{2}}{15}$$